# Read-only vs. Write-protected

Tags: memory, storage, flash-memory

From an information security aspect, is there a difference between saying "**read-only**" or "**write-protected**" storage/memory?

Is there a chance that a read-only memory would not be write-protected at the same time?

In addition, is the OTP (one-Time-Programmable) memories better described as write-protected memories or as Read-only memories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read-only means one can only read from it. Write-protected means that writing is possible but controlled. Those controls can fail.

If "read-only" is defined in the hardware, then it will always be write-protected at the same time.

OTP memory is OTP. After being burned, it is read-only.